# WPF Localized Extension MVVM Binding

Tags: wpf, localization

I am trying to bind a property called ["SampleName"] that is declared in ViewModel. Here SampleName is key. However, when trying below code, it display's empty.

```
<TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{lex:BLoc Value=SampleName}" lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly="SAS.Resources" lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary="Report" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextDecorations="Underline" FontWeight="DemiBold" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding Path=SpanCount}" Grid.Column="0"/>
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I was using the sugested answer, but that's not 100% stable and thread safe. Now I am using this solution instead.

My View:

```
xmlns:lex="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com"

<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=LocProxy, Path=Result}"/>
<lex:LocProxy Name="LocProxy"
           Source="{Binding NameOfResourceKey}"/>
```

MyViewModel:

```
public string NameOfResourceKey { get; set; }
```

and then set it like this int ViewModel:

```
// Use your way to access classis Resources.resx file
NameOfResourceKey = nameof(Properties.Resources.YourLocalizedMessageKey);
// Use your function to RaiseProperty     
RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(NameOfResourceKey));
```

So you need to reference your Resource in resource file by nameof, set it as a source of lex:LocProxy and then Bind to LoxProxy Result, wherever you need your localized string. Quite simple, and then GUI is handlig all the localization, which is optimal.

And for Raise the property, you can use the function from bruno.almeida (OnPropertyChanged), or use for Example MVVMLight nuget package and inherit ViewModelBase in your ViewModel as I do.

Answer (score 1):

I checked source code and don't think BLoc was made to do that. But i found other way to archive the same result.

Based on [this](https://github.com/SeriousM/WPFLocalizationExtension/issues/87#issuecomment-174510689) answer, i came up with this solution. Instead of giving the resource key to the view, gives the resource value. If the Culture changes, then the value also change. This is the core implementation:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        // Properties.Resources is my Resources.resx file and String1 is my resource key
        BindPropertyToResource(nameof(Name), nameof(Properties.Resources.String1));
    }


    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void BindPropertyToResource(string propertyName, string resourceKey){
        WPFLocalizeExtension.Providers.ResxLocalizationProvider resxLocalizationProvider
            = WPFLocalizeExtension.Providers.ResxLocalizationProvider.Instance;

        WPFLocalizeExtension.Providers.ResxLocalizationProvider.SetDefaultAssembly(resxLocalizationProvider, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name);
        WPFLocalizeExtension.Providers.ResxLocalizationProvider.SetDefaultDictionary(resxLocalizationProvider, nameof(Properties.Resources));

        var targetProperty = this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        var locBinding = new WPFLocalizeExtension.Extensions.LocTextExtension(resourceKey);

        locBinding.SetBinding(this, targetProperty);
    }


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members
}
```

Hope this workaround solves your problem.